# Is a negative question like "Do not you have a car?" idiomatic?

Tags: questions

Is it also correct to say,

> **Do not** you have a car?

or is the correct way the contracted form,

> **Don't** you have a car?

Comment: The closure of this question was too quick and too uncritical., The accepted answer to the so-called duplicate lacks references, makes no reference to the Scottish use of "Do you not", and does not compare "do you ...", Do you not ..." and "Don't you ...". Reopen.

Comment: Are you asking about "Do not you have a car?" (as in the title) or "Do you not have a car?" (as in the body of the question)?

Comment: I believe that the "Do not you..." form used to be common some centuries ago and that it was compressed to "Don't" you. Changes to colloquial English since have led to the expanded "Do not you.." form passing out of use, although the "Do you not..." form still persists to some extent, but the compressed "Don't you..." is now by far the most widely used.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? ['Why is this not' versus 'why is not this'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16585/why-is-this-not-versus-why-is-not-this). Isn't this? [Is 'don't you know?' the same as 'do not you know?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14287/is-dont-you-know-the-same-as-do-not-you-know)

Comment: @BoldBen: Several centuries ago (around 1 ½, by Ngrams, at least in writing), the correct form would have been *Have you not a car?* (Although this just applies to the verb *have*.)

Comment: @PeterShor That's not the expanded version of "Don't you have..." though. I believe "Do not you have..." to be older but If it never existed then I don't believe that the compressed form would have evolved.

Comment: @BoldBen: The expanded form *Do not you ...* existed for other verbs.  (For example *Do not you love him*, from Shakespeare's *All's Well that Ends Well*.)  But it was not used for the verb *have*. (For example, *have you not beadles in 
your town, and things called whips?* from Shakespeare's *Henry VI, Part II*.) I think that to Elizabethan ears, asking: *Do not you have ...* would have sounded like asking *Don't you be ashamed?* rather than *Aren't you ashamed?* sounds to us.

Comment: So really, I was nitpicking on your comment. My apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

"Don't you have..." is idiomatic. But written without the contraction it should be:

> "Do you not have.."

Contractions become words in their own right, so it is not surprising that the construction is different. The same is true of "*can't you...*", which means "*can you not...*".